# How to stop/start Neo4j server via .bat script in windows

Tags: neo4j

When running the neo4j server in Linux, we have several commands - start, stop, restart, etc - to control it via the command line.

In windows, [the manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/re01.html) simply says:

> Usage - Windows
>   Neo4j.bat
>
> Double-clicking on the Neo4j.bat script will start the server in a console. To quit, just press control-C in the console window.

**But how do I stop it if I've started it by executing neo4j.bat from a .bat file of my own, and thus don't have a console window?**

For context: I'm working on an unmanaged extension, so I need to rebuild my jar, move it into the plugins directory and restart the server each time I make a change. It'd be a pain in the ass to do this manually, so (when when I was working in Linux) I had Intellij rebuild the artifact and execute a .sh script that moved the resultant jar into /plugins and restarted neo4j.

```
'/path/to/neo4j/bin/neo4j' stop
rm /path/to/neo4j/plugins/api.jar
mv /project/path/artifacts/graphapi.jar /path/to/neo4j/plugins/api.jar 
'/path/to/neo4j' start
```

How do I do the same in windows using a .bat file?

I've tried this:

```
del "C:/path/to/neo/plugins/api.jar
move "C:/project/path/artifacts/api.jar" "C:/path/to/neo/plugins/api.jar"
C:/neo/bin/Neo4j.bat
```

hoping that simply calling Neo4j.bat again would stop the current process and start another, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: call it with "start neo4j.bat"

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you can stop Neo4j server by executing: `neo4j.bat stop`

Let me show it in details for those who might be new to the command line:

1. We need to know where Neo4j is located. If you remember where did you extract it - good, you can skip this step. For others: open Task Manager and look for `Commons Daemon Service Runner` [here how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qthAU.png) right mouse click, open Properties and look for its Location path. Find this path in your file manager. We are looking for bin folder with `neo4j.bat` file.
2. Open command line and write `cd` and then paste your path, hit enter. You should jump to that folder with `neo4j.bat` file.
3. Stop the server: Type `neo4j.bat stop` and execute. It will ask for your permission .

after that, you can double check and type 'neo4j.bat status` t be sure it's stopped.

P.S. After Windows reboot neo4j server will be automatically restarted. If you don't want this (it consumes up to 500Mb of memory, at least in my DB ~64k records) you should uninstall the service.
Execute `neo4j.bat uninstall-service` in that directory.

Cheers!